# Fill <select> using mySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**I have the following drop down list**

```
<select name="SelP">
    <option value="0">Please Select...</option>
    <option value="35">LS1</option>
    <option value="35">LS2</option>
    <option value="35">LS3</option>
    <option value="35">LS4</option>
    <option value="35">Postcode not Listed</option>
</select>
```

and I have written the PHP to work like so

```
<?php
//Sample Database Connection Syntax for PHP and MySQL.
//Connect To Database
$hostname="localhost";
$username="alloytes_achenry";
$password="**PASSWORD HERE**";
$dbname="alloytes_acquote";
$usertable="LocationTable";
$postcode="postcode";
mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die ("    <html>%MINIFYHTML4333ddb1f6ba50276851b9f9854a5c817%</html>");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
# Check If Record Exists
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE minimumprice = 35";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$postcode = $row["$postcode"];
echo "$postcode";
}
}
?>
```

This works well and returns the postcode value. I now need to edit the PHP to return both **$postcode** and **$minimumprice** , and then to populate the table with the postcode going as the text and the $minimumprice as the value (value="$minimumprice").

Any advice where to start would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Henry

**TEST CODE 1**

```
<?php
//Sample Database Connection Syntax for PHP and MySQL.
//Connect To Database
$hostname="localhost";
$username="alloytes_achenry";
$password="f(6@g0^O#2kT";
$dbname="alloytes_acquote";
$usertable="LocationTable";
$postcode="postcode";
$minimumprice="minimumprice";
mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die (" <html>%MINIFYHTML4333ddb1f6ba50276851b9f9854a5c817%</html>");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
# Check If Record Exists
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$postcode = $row['postcode'];
$minimumprice = $row['minimumprice'];
echo <<<EOL
<option value="$minimumprice">$postcode</option>

EOL;
}
}
?>
</form>
```

Returns Just the postcode, any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: also, this is **WHERE minimumprice = 35";** but I need it to pull all values, and I am not sure how to :( sorry for me being such a noob...

Comment: just to clarify, i think it would need to echo

echo "<option value="$minimumprice">"$postcode"</option>";

but all of the rows in the table, not just a single echo

Comment: Please don't use the mysql_* API anymore, the community is deprecating it. It's highly unsafe and inefficient. Use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements instead.

Comment: Wherever you found this terrible code, forget about it and start again here: http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: no I am totally goosed, feel like I don't know anything about PHP again :(

Comment: error on line 11, which is "    $pdo = new PDO(" copied straight from your link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $postcode = $row['postcode'];
   $minimumprice = $row['minimumprice'];
   echo <<<EOL
<option value="$minimumprice">$postcode</option>

EOL;
}
```

note the use of a [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc)

Comment: how do i remove this line? **$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE minimumprice = 35";** as it only selects 1 value here

Comment: plus this is also returning a blank value, please could you edit my PHP and point out the errors I have made too?

Regards

Comment: @HenryAspden It's not very polite to ask others to do stuff for you

Comment: @JuanMendes asking, I was, I am asking for help, I am trying code after code after code... and looping round and round and round... :( I am sorry, I didn't mean to be rude, i just thought it might help to work backwards from some successfull code

Comment: worked a charm once entered into the live version... Thanks for your help !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$select = '<select name="SelP"> <option value="0">Please Select...</option>';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $postcode = $row["postcode"];
        $minimumprice = $row["minimumprice"];
        $select .= "<option value=\"$postcode\">$minimumprice</option>";
    }
}
$select .= '</select>';
```

Comment: meh, I think my first bit of my PHP is wrong, can you please help by editing my PHP with the addition of yours and pointing out anywhere I have made a mistake? This code isn't erroring, but is returning a blank page :(

Comment: Turn on all error notification and show us some error messages

Comment: ok, one quick question, if my mySQL and my webhosting are both on the same server, can I use "localhost" or is there another way?

regards

Comment: Yes, you can use localhost, you can also use the actual servername, but localhost will still work when you move it to a different server

Comment: I don't know the server's name, only the IP 81.19.185.86

Comment: Try changing your query to just be `SELECT * FROM $usertable` to see if you're just not getting any results. Add debugging statements to the else clause of the `if ($resuls)` and see if you ever go into your `while` loop

Comment: I have added the latest version of code above, thanks for all your hope with this, hope you have the patients to help me further. Henry

Comment: Please don't use the mysql_* API anymore, the community is deprecating it. It's highly unsafe and inefficient. Use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements instead.

Comment: i have no idea what this means :o

Answer (score 0):

The only thing sent to the server is what you have in the `value=""` part of the `option`.  Nothing else gets sent.  If you really need to send both of those values, you might want to change the `value` to be something like `35,LS4`.  Have both values in there separated by a comma.  Then on the serverside when you catch it, just `explode()` that value into an array and use the 0th and 1st element accordingly.

Comment: no just the value need to be caried forward to the Javascript element, the postcode is just for refrence purposes to the user...